# I just failed PIP, should I ask for management to terminate my employment?

Tags: termination, performance-reviews, performance, severance

Today (June 19th) is my last day of my Performance Improvement Plan (PIP) and I know I failed it because my boss told me I am not passing. As of right now, I have not receive a notice termination. I do have a job lined up so I would rather for the company to terminate me rather than resigning myself. I live in British Columbia, Canada, so I am entitled to severance if I am fired for performance issue.

I want the company to officially announce my termination as working here is giving me too much stress and anxiety. Should I take the initiative and reach out to my boss about how we should move forward after failing my PIP? Or should I wait it out? My boss will be taking a two week long vacation starting on the 21st of June 2023.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146815/discussion-on-question-by-fielddesign-i-just-failed-pip-should-i-ask-for-manage); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 40):

> Or should I wait it out?

Yes.

---

[I have accepted an offer from another company. I start on (Monday) July 10th. I am required to give 14 day notice.](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/191922/i-just-failed-pip-should-i-ask-for-management-to-terminate-my-employment#comment631583_191922)

Begin removing personal items at work today.

Provide 2-week notice on the end of the work week (about this Friday, June 23). [@Stephan Branczyk](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/191922/i-just-failed-pip-should-i-ask-for-management-to-terminate-my-employment/191932#comment631588_191922)

- Perform as well as able this week and up to your last work-day.
- Boss on vacation - irrelevant.  If needed, work with your boss's boss or whoever is the temporary replacement.
- "I would rather for the company to terminate me rather than resigning myself." --> Weak goal.  Rather than trying to optimize any payout from the current company, focus on the next step in your career.  Do what makes most sense to start that job right.

**Look forward, not back.**
Good luck.

Comment: Some severance pay may sound like a good deal but it's nothing in grand scheme of things. OP can earn much more than money if he/she rather work on their skills and ethics over the years.

Comment: @CodePanda True.  In terms of optimizing the exit, both OP and OP's current employer aim to optimize their own economic benefit.   I suspect the one with more experience (the employer) will win this round.  The better and more fruitful approach for OP is the new start and opportunities with the new employee.

Comment: Why does it matter who wins? It's not a life changing amount for anyone. If I was OP, I would rather be introspecting how things end up like this. Ending up in PIP is not a normal thing and should be taken more seriously

Comment: @CodePanda What mattes is how the stressed OP uses the current time and energy during this important serious time. OP needs to focus on the next step and not try to win a severance.  If OP gets one or not - fine, yet it is the first impressions, the first weeks on the new job that are most important - things OP is not asking about.

Answer (score 23):

None of us are mind-readers and can predict whether your boss will fire you or not. If you want to know for sure, just ask him/her ASAP ideally before they go on a vacation.

As you mentioned, you are starting a new job soon. As such, try to have this conversation ASAP. If it's not the outcome you want, give your resignation.

Also I should add, it seems like you don't like this job and you are actively trying to get fired intentionally. It's bit unprofessional behavior. If you don't like a job, you are supposed to resign / sue them (if you have a basis). If they are being unprofessional, the solution is not to stoop at their level. You should maintain professional integrity regardless.

Comment: I am not trying to get fired intentionally as they have made up their mind by putting me on a PIP.

Comment: "you are starting a new job soon" is not really true. OP "has a job lined up". There are various ways that new job could fail to actually start. You risk having no job and no severance if you resign one job before the other one actually starts. Since the original company states they want to terminate the OP, it's on them to actually do it.

Comment: Good luck paying your bills with "professional integrity", corporations don't care about their workers, will fire or lay them off for BS reasons, why should OP not get the severance he's earned, after all they have already put him on PIP which is just a way for them to gather data to justify firing you, I don't see how OP is going out of his way to get fired.

Answer (score 7):

If you can afford being unemployed for 3 days and if you would like to leave your current company with the best impression, I would give notice today.

You mention the job is causing you stress and anxiety, and you already have your next job lined up.

Just looking at the calendar: today is June 20, so if you have a 2-week notice today, your last day of work would be 4 July. You have a confirmed start date of 10 July; assuming you're working a usual M-F schedule, that would leave you between jobs for a total of 3 days, (5-7 July).

Since your boss is leaving for two weeks starting tomorrow, giving notice after he's out of the office might be a way to avoid confronting him. Not sure if that's your goal or relevant to the objective of your PIP. Not having that interaction may also be viewed as cowardly; we can't read your boss's mind or what his issues are with your performance.

I would give notice phrasing it this way: "I anticipate my last working day to be 04 July, but am willing to work through 07 July to facilitate the transition, if requested."

Depending on your company's policies and whatever you've got going on with your PIP,  the company may ask you to not come back the day you give notice, so be prepared for that, as well.

But...

All that being said, there's another way I could be reading your question: have you been purposely (consciously or unconsciously) giving your company reasons to terminate you so you can collect a severance? Already having another job lined up, it seems like you've been preparing to leave anyway. Are you playing chicken with your company, seeing who blinks first, hoping to collect a severance on your way out the door?

Answer (score 5):

There's a chance that they are aware of your job offer, and see it as a beautiful solution to the dilemma of what to do with you.  Letting you be hired away is their cheapest option, and its spares everyone awkward meetings, bad feelings, etc. They're not worried about 2-1/2 weeks of your salary.

Asking management to terminate your employment is bizarre.  It seems like you don't understand how unemployment works.  Right off the bat you get **[no payments](https://www.canada.ca/en/services/benefits/ei/ei-regular-benefit/benefit-amount.html) for the first week**.  Then you only get 55% of your wage, capped at $650 per week. And it's not free money - they can ding your employer for that, and even go after you to recover it if you're high-paying. Being terminated for cause also affects your eligibility.

And if you're shy about talking to your boss, how will you feel when the employer objects and you have to go into an audit and fight for your claim.

This all sounds like a clever plan to get less money lol.

Keep working. On June 23, give your notice to whoever your direct report is while your boss is away - a coworker assigned to cover for your boss, their boss, HR, whoever.  It is common to fire a person "on the spot" and have security watch them collect their items and walk them out of the building.   It's also common to let them work the two weeks, do transition planning, have you train your replacement, etc.  Hard to say how it'll go.

"Letting you work out the 2 weeks" is the best scenario and you get 100% of pay.

"Firing you immediately for giving 2 week notice" - guess what that is! That's a *termination without cause!* So you get your wish and are legally entitled to unemployment. Nothing for the first week then 55% for the second week.  27.5% pay! Awesome!  Yes, they will protest you resigned, but you will point out you resigned *as of July 10* so you're certainly entitled to 2 weeks of unemployment. (week 1 being $0).

Comment: Severance and unemployment benefits are not the same thing. Also, are you talking about Canada here?

Answer (score -1):

PIP basically means "we plan to fire you, and are working on the best way to get you to make mistakes so we can accelerate the process"--you have a target on you, and they definitely plan to fire you. Your boss and HR are definitely not your friends; they will never be "on your side".

If you work in the software industry, never allow yourself to become fired (because of the impact on career reputation); instead, just resign if you are at all unhappy--you are in the driver's seat here. There are so many opportunities available in software--don't be afraid of the future.

[Ignore the 14 days notification--just quit](https://www.welcomebc.ca/Work-in-B-C/Working-in-B-C); send an email to HR and your boss saying you immediately resign. But be sure to get your belongings, etc, out of the office before sending the notification.

Comment: I think the OP is afraid that if they just quit they will lose whatever severance they are entitled to if they get fired.

Comment: I haven't found any justification in the link you posted for ignoring the 14 days notification and just quitting. Sounds like a terrible idea to me, since it will imply burning bridges with your current employer

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki "Quitting
Workers may decide to quit (leave) a job. There is no law saying workers have to give early notice. But it is still better to tell the employer early. Most people tell their employers 2 weeks before they finish. The employer does not have to pay any compensation if you quit." - the link points out there is no legal requirement for notice in BC.

Comment: I don't know what it's like in BC, but in the UK resigning without notice is a breach of contract and could result in big trouble.

Comment: @Yakk, regarding "But it is still better to tell the employer early." begs the question: better for whom? (I know, not your words, just quoting employment law.)

Comment: @AndrewLeach There is a link covering that in this answer, right under "ignore the 14 days notification".  Employees are, in general, not indentured to service in BC.

Comment: "the impact on career reputation" source? And also, "ignore the 14 days notice", how do you expect that reflects on your reputation?

Comment: @Yakk in BC (and the rest of Canada), it's often specified in further details in the contract. (if that was the case, and the contract did specify 2 weeks notice, as is common practice, ignoring it would be a breach of contract)

Comment: @Yakk that's frankly extraordinarily risky advice, in Canada. Canadian courts have held that there's a common law "reasonable notice" requirement to both sides (there is no "at will" employment anywhere in Canada). [Consbec Inc v Walker](https://www.vwlawyers.ca/blog/resignation-regrets-employees-failure-to-provide-reasonable-notice-of-departure-costs-him-5611611) was decided *in BC*, and the court awarded $50k to the employer for "wrongful resignation".

Comment: @mbrig this situation seems rather different from the one described in Consbec Inc v Walker, where it says "Nevertheless, the Court noted that for wrongful resignation, the test for damages considers loss of opportunity as a result of insufficient notice, not loss of earnings". The OP is already in the cross-hairs of the company--they want this person to leave, so if OP wants to leave earlier, it really cannot cause "loss of opportunity".

Comment: @mikequentel "loss of opportunity" seems to be very broad (broader than actual loss of earnings). The following sentence there is "Examining the facts, Consbec was deprived of the opportunity to retain a replacement employee". Together with "The Court began by recalling that the purpose of employee notice is to 'provide time for the employer to make arrangements to have the work that the departing employee looked after by others, or to find another employee.'"; I'd worry that that would easily apply to any leaving without notice, even if they want you gone already.